# Turning csv file into api

Tags: database, csv, https

I want to create a project. I have a huge list of data in a single .csv file. It has millions of data and I want to access them remotely using an API call.
My CSV files looks similar like this:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 20 |
| Blue | 25 |

It's a single CSV file and it has over millions of data.
I want to turn this CSV file into a API so that I can access it from anywhere anytime using HTTPS request.
Like, **[www.myapi.example/api/csvfile/red](http://www.myapi.example/api/csvfile/red)**
When I submit this call, I should get response **Age:20** Something like that.
Please give me Idea how to do that.

I expect to get response like this after a HTTPS request:

> {"Blue":"25"}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... Your best bet is probably to import your data into a database and query that from your API.  Though if you *really want* to have the API directly query a large CSV file, you can certainly do that too.  It'll be slower, but possible.